# Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties - with babel.config.js

Tags: react-native, config, babeljs, babel-plugin

I am trying to use [ConfirmGoogleCaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-recaptcha-v2) in a **React Native** app, after installing it I get the following error:

```
class ConfirmGoogleCaptcha extends Component {
 state = {
       ^
     show: false
 }
 show = () => {
```

> Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

Most of the answers that I've read suggest adding presets and plugins into `.babelrc` file, that did not work for me. Also many answers and the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) say that `babel.config.js` can solve the problem, here is my **babel.config.js file**:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {loose: true}],
    };
};
```

I only want to solve this using `babel.config.js` file.

Comment: did you find the fix?